# Exceeding time constraint of 300 seconds when taking coefficients of some expressions from schur polynomial

Tags: performance-tuning, warning-messages, combinatorics

I have written a code that takes coefficients of some expressions 
from schur function, but it seems to take a lot of time, and 
*Mathematica* will stop after 300 seconds saying that it's over the time constraint of 300 seconds.

> Simplify::time: Time spent on a transformation exceeded 300 seconds, and the transformation was aborted. Increasing the value of TimeConstraint option may improve the result of simplification. >>

Is there any way to remove this time constraint and let *Mathematica* run for any amount of time it needs?

Or, I can also upload my code to find any way to optimize it.

Below is my code and intd.m is a package that provides integrateUnitaryHaar, CharacterSymmetricGroup and other functions.

```
Get["intd.m"]
λ = some partitions such as {2,2}
n = Total[λ]; //Weight of lambda or weight of lambda + 1
A = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, n}]]; //Diagonal matrix
B = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Subscript[b, i], {i, n}]]; //Diagonal matrix
A' = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Subscript[a, i + 1], {i, n - 1}]]; // A without a_1
B' = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Subscript[b, i + 1], {i, n - 1}]];  // B without b_1
U = Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; // Arbitrary matrix
X = A . U . B . ConjugateTranspose[U]; // X = AUBU*

subpartitionQ[p1_, p2_] := 
AllTrue[Range[Length[p2]], p1[[#1]] <= p2[[#1]] & ]; 
subpartitions[λ_] := Select[Flatten[(#1 - 1 & ) /@ 
       Table[IntegerPartitions[total, {Length[λ]}], 
         {total, 
   Length[λ] + Total[λ] - λ[[1]], 
   Length[λ] + Total[λ]}], 1], 
   subpartitionQ[#1, λ] & ]; 
subpt = Reverse[Sort[subpartitions[λ]]]; 
// subpartitions of lambda sorted by lexicographic order.

p[λ_, X_] := 
Product[Tr[MatrixPower[X, λ[[j]]]], {j, Length[λ]}]; 

χ[λ_, μ_] := 
CharacterSymmetricGroup[λ, μ]; 

z[μ_] := 
Product[i^Count[μ, i]*Count[μ, i]!, {i, Total[μ]}]; 

s[λ_, X_] := 
Sum[χ[λ, μ]*(p[μ, X]/z[μ]), {μ, 
IntegerPartitions[Total[λ]]}]; 

shurAt1 = SchurPolynomialAt1[λ, n]; 

//functions that produce power sums, schur functions. 

left = Expand[s[λ, X]]; 
ld[δ_] := Total[λ] - Total[δ]; 
subpexp[μ_, σ_] := s[μ,A']*s[σ,B']*(a_1)^ld[\    [Mu]]*(b_1)^ld[σ];

intgrd[μ_, σ_] := 
Coefficient[left, subpexp[μ, σ]];

ls = Length[subpt]; 

table = Table[
Simplify[IntegrateUnitaryHaar[Abs[Subscript[u, 1, 1]]^2*
  Block[{μ, σ, sub, IU}, μ = 
    subpt[[i]]; σ = subpt[[j]]; 
   IU = intgrd[μ, σ]; 
            sub = IU*subpexp[μ, σ]; left = left - sub; 
   IU], {u, d}]], {i, 1, ls}, 
   {j, 1, ls}];
```

I think it takes the most time from taking coefficient since the schur polynomial gets very huge even at dimension 3, or partition of weight 3. It contains thousands of terms.

Comment: Please post example code.

Comment: Perhaps `SetOptions[Simplify, TimeConstraint -> 1000]`.  Hard to answer without more details.  Usually, I find, if a simplification step takes more than 300 seconds, then I'm in trouble.

Comment: I uploaded by code. Thanks

Comment: Of course, another form of my suggestion is contained in the message, [`ref/message/FullSimplify/time`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FullSimplify/time.html) and in the documentation for [`TimeConstraint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstraint.html)